# Getting century from year

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So, I have a problem where I have to return the century. I have made a code but it fails for years like 1700 or 1800.
My question is, how can I make a special case that if the year is fixed, like 2000 it only divides the year by 100?
I have tried with

```
element.slice(-2);
```

but it didn't work.
Here's my current code

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    var x = Math.floor(year/100) + 1;
    return x; 
}
```

Comment: Your `centuryFromYear` doesn't fail for me. What are the expected results for the inputs `1700` and  `1800`?

Comment: A much larger issue will be negative year numbers (where `slice` approaches fail even harder)

Answer (score 23):

you can have it shortest as:

```
return Math.ceil(year/100);
```

Comment: [Math.ceil on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) is somebody needs more info from the documentation.

Answer (score 12):

Subtract 1 from `year` first:

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    return Math.floor((year-1)/100) + 1;
}
```

Examples:

```
centuryFromYear(1999) // 20
centuryFromYear(2000) // 20
centuryFromYear(2001) // 21
```

---

Better yet, use `Math.ceil(year/100)` as in [Yakir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691787/2700898).

Answer (score 4):

Last two digits:

```js
let myNumber = 2000;
console.log(myNumber.toString().slice(-2))
```

First two digits:

```js
let myNumber = 2000;
console.log(myNumber.toString().slice(0,2))
```

Final function:

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
  if(typeof year == 'string')
    if(year.toString().slice(-2) == '00')
      return year.toString().slice(0,2);
    else
      return (Math.floor(+year/100) +1).toString();
  else if(typeof year == 'number')
    return Math.floor((year-1)/100) + 1;
  else
    return undefined;
} 
    
console.log(centuryFromYear("2000"));
console.log(centuryFromYear("1901"));
console.log(centuryFromYear("2002"));
console.log(centuryFromYear(2002));
console.log(centuryFromYear(1999));
console.log(centuryFromYear(2000));
```

Comment: Great answer  @attersson, thanks, however, I implemented an if statment and it still doesn't work, do you have any ideea? my coode looks like this now function centuryFromYear(year) {
    var x = Math.floor(year/100) + 1;
    if(x.toString().slice(-2) == '00') {
       var x = year/100;
        return x;
    }
    return x;
}

Comment: I edited my solution. Please find the function. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for that special case just by doing something like this:

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    var x = Math.floor(year / 100);
    if (year % 100 === 0)
        return x;
    else
        return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra check in your function that checks if the year is a rounded century like 2000 or 1800. Here's how that would look.

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    var x = year % 100 === 0 ? year/100 : Math.floor(year/100) + 1;
    return x; 
}

console.log('2000 => ', centuryFromYear(2000));
console.log('2001 => ', centuryFromYear(2001));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
var testInt = Number.isInteger(year/100);
    if (year >= 1 && testInt == true ) {
        return Math.floor(year/100);
    }
    else if ( year >= 1 && testInt == false) {
        return Math.floor(year/100) + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please try to explain clearly when you answered questions

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for this:

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    return Math.floor((year + 99) / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First subtract a year from the year to avoid messing up every 100 year.

```
int centuryFromYear(int year) {
int century = Math.floor((year-1) / 100) + 1;
return century;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
 return Math.ceil(year / 100)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this adds anything over the existing answers...

Answer (score 0):

```
//The code work fine

function solution(year) {
    
    let result = year / 100 + 1;
    
    console.log(Math.floor(result));
}

solution(1905);//20
```